# php loop through sql result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `sales_product` with columns

```
sales_product_id, sales_id, type, class, age
```

I have a query in php saying

```
$sql = "SELECT * from sales_product WHERE sales_id = " . $_GET['sales_id];
```

Suppose this query returns two rows.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

How do I loop through this result and save in an array so that later on I can retrieve data like

```
echo $sales_product[$i]['sales_product_id'];
echo $sales_product[$i]['sales_product_id'];
........
```

Comment: No No No to mysql_* extension

Comment: @fluty Go on ! Suggest other solution.

Answer (score 5):

Do `mysql_fetch_assoc` in `while` loop:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows[] = array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    echo $row['sales_product_id'];
    $rows[] = $row;
}

var_dump($rows);
```

Comment: but how do I save each row in an array?

Comment: sorry could you pls tell me how do I loop through this $rows[] array in order to display each rows

Comment: Use `foreach` then:  `foreach ( $rows as $row ) { var_dump($row); }`

Comment: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["sales_product_id"];
}
```

Comment: but how do I save each row in an array?

Comment: @KOU $row is an array with keys. If you want to use integers i.e $row[0] then you could use mysql_fetch_array() instead of fetch_assoc

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

[mysql_fetch_array();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

**Note**

Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

[mysqli_fetch_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

[PDOStatement::fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    echo $row['columnName'];
}
```

Use mysql_fetch_array() if u need with index

Answer (score 0):

check this one.

```
$sql="SELECT sales_product_id, sales_id, type, class, age From sales_product";
$sales= $db->query($sql);
while($sale = $db->fetchByAssoc($sales))
{
    echo $sales['sales_product_id'];
    echo $sales['type'];
 // here instead echo uyou will add data in your array

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, this will give you the format you requested (untested):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sales_product[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since mysql_ has been declared deprecated so i am going to answer your question with
mysqli_* extension

```
//Prepare an SQL statement for execution
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from sales_product WHERE sales_id = ?");

//bind parameter to the prepared statement      
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['sales_id]);

//execute it 
$stmt->execute();

//store the result  
$result = $stmt->get_result();

//loop through the  result set
while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{

      $salesIds[]  = $myrow["sales_product_id"];

}
```

For more information please refer to php documentation.
Thanks